# Why does an image is distorted when I set it using GroundOverlay in my Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to set a screenshot of a map into another map using GroundOverlay provided by Google Maps.

First I save the bounds of the map when I take the screenshot. I get them using

```
borders = GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

After when I set the screenshot to the GroundOverlay image using that bounds, the image appears distorted. I did it like this

```
GroundOverlayOptions offlineMap = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                            .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myBitmap))
                            .transparency(0)
                            .positionFromBounds(borders);
                    imageOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(offlineMap);
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[Screenshot of the image overlay distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL2K3.jpg)

Why is happening this? How can I set the image correctly?

**EDITED**

I could set the image without distorsion passing the *LatLng* coordinates of the center of the image and the width of the image, but the thing is that the *GroundOverlayOptions* object needs the width in kilometers, and I calculated using the distance between the two bot points of the image in the moment that is captured.

My problem is, the image is set with correct proportions, but in the wrong place.
How can I save the attributes to set the image in the exactly same position on the map as when it was taken?

Comment: Seems your code is ok. Probably `borders ` has wrong coords. May be that was because `borders = GoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;` called in not appropriate place. Try to call it in `GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that, but I get exactly the same result. I edited my question because now i could set it without distorsion, but not in the right place. Hope you can help me @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: Seems issue is in `borders` object. Try to Logcat it coords and analyze.

Comment: I did it, with center and borders, but they are being taken fine. I am doing it now with `.position(center, distance);`. The center is fine, but I think the problem is the distance (calculated as `Location.distanceBetween(...)`and the latitude and longitude of both south borders), and after I change it to meters (using floats, as is required) Do you think is problem of that? What else can it be? Thank you @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: Can you contact me by mail and some help? I am getting mad, big help with my thesis _trollmada@gmail.com_ @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: Paste code where you get `borders`. Seems there is no need to calc distance or something else. Just call `.positionFromBounds(borders)` and everything should works.

Comment: I took it using `curScreen=gMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;`during a method triggered when the user clicks a button to screenshot the map. I tested it logging the LatLng coordinates in the OnMapClick method and tapping in the corners, and the LatLngBounds are very close to them, but if I set it using this method, the image get distorted. This is why I'm using the `.position(center, distance)` method to set the overlay @AndriiOmelchenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, which gets screenshot on `mScreenshotButton` press, than add it as overlay on `mAddOverlayButton` press:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private Button mAddOverlayButton;
    private Button mScreenshotButton;
    private Bitmap mScreenshot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mScreenshotButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_screenshot_button);
        mScreenshotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getMapScreenshot();
            }
        });

        mAddOverlayButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_overlay_button);
        mAddOverlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LatLngBounds borders = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

                GroundOverlayOptions overlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                        .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mScreenshot))
                        .transparency(0f)
                        .positionFromBounds(borders);

                mGoogleMap.addGroundOverlay(overlay);
            }
        });

        mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    public void getMapScreenshot()
    {
        GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            Bitmap bitmap;

            @Override
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                mScreenshot = snapshot;
            }
        };

        mGoogleMap.snapshot(callback);
    }

}
```

And there is no any distortion.  Seems you didn't get `borders` properly.

Comment: YES! It works! Do you know how to set properly the rotation? Because if the map is rotated when I take the screenshot, the image get distorted too. Thank you so much for your reply mate!

Comment: @thEmadA 1. You are welcome! 2. It's other question.

Comment: You are right, I created a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641839/how-can-i-rotate-a-groundoverlay-set-using-latlngbounds)